# Google colab can't restart runtime when in cell output iframe

Tags: google-colaboratory

Google tells me "The shortcut "Restart runtime" is disabled when a code cell output iframe is active. Use the escape key to leave the iframe and enter the shortcut again." when I try to restart after clicking a cell output.

I was just curious why I can't restart when on a cell output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the output frame is focused, keyboard shortcuts end up directed there first.

Of course, you can always select the restart runtime menu regardless of keyboard focus.

[image]